# SSL https magento frontend layout issue - Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, ssl, https, magento-1.9

I want to access a magento 1.9 using https
SSL installed.
but still layout does not include the css and js with https url
and not able to access the login page too.
Changes done in site Configuration:
1.Secure: Site base url as https://www.example.org
2.Use Secure URLs in Frontend as Yes
3.Auto-redirect to Base URL as No
4.Offloader header as SSL_OFFLOADED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to work site using https are:
In Configuration,
In Unsecure section
Base url : remove http

In secure section
Base url : add https

Answer (score 0):

Base url and secure url should have a trailing slash, ie

```
https://example.com/
```

Comment: have you refreshed all your caches? if you view the source of the page, you will see what is going on in the <head> section of the page